# Append value of one table into column key of another

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 1 table with users in them like so:

```
id  name    email       status
---------------------------------
1   Jane    j@ne.do     active
2   Jack    j@ck.do     active
3   Jane    j@ne.do     inactive
4   Jack    j@ck.do     inactive
```

I also have data table like so:

```
id  user_id key         value
------------------------------
1   1       firts_name  Jane
2   1       last_name   Do
3   2       city        Amsterdam
4   2       first_name  Jack
```

Now i want to have them like so in one query:

```
id  name    email       status      firts_name  last_name   city
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Jane    j@ne.do     active      Jane        Do          NULL
2   Jack    j@ck.do     active      Jack        NULL        Amsterdam
3   Jane    j@ne.do     inactive    NULL        NULL        NULL
4   Jack    j@ck.do     inactive    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

is that even possible in one query?

Normaly i do 2 queries and then combine the 2 in php but i am curious if this is possible.

Comment: Do you also normally have duplicate emails/usernames in your users table?

Comment: No, this is just for example! I also make sure the keys are not the same. Thats done in code. I just copy/pasted this for example!

Comment: @MarcvdM: use sql joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily by joining the tables and using `CASE` statements:

```
select
    u.id,
    u.name,
    u.email,
    u.status,
    max(case when a.`key`='first_name' then a.value end) as first_name,
    max(case when a.`key`='last_name' then a.value end) as last_name,
    max(case when a.`key`='city' then a.value end) as city
from
    users u
left join
    attr a on a.user_id = u.id
group by
    u.id
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66086/4

Comment: what if the attr.key is unpredictable! like there can be more added allong the way! can it be dynamicly?

Comment: How do you write a query that returns a dynamic list of columns?  About the only way that can be done is dynamic SQL, i.e., generate SQL code on-the-fly and execute it.  If that is the case, your best bet is probably to generate the dynamic query with PHP, or do the data manipulation entirely in PHP as you already are.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a prepared statement:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal, a correlated sub-query would work. something like:

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    `name`,
    `status`,
    (SELECT `value` FROM `table2` WHERE `user_id`=`table1`.`id` AND `key`='first_name') AS first_name,
    (SELECT `value` FROM `table2` WHERE `user_id`=`table1`.`id` AND `key`='last_name') AS last_name
FROM `table1`
```

However, I have a feeling like there is a better way to do what you are looking for.